# Binding to an inherited (grand-child) object?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have a ListBox whose datacontext is an:

```
ObservableCollection<Item>
```

Item is a base class, and from it inherits a Potion class, and then from that inherits a HealthPotion class.

So:

Item -> Potion -> HealthPotion

My ListBox template looks something like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,17">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyFromItem}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyFromPotion}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyFromHealthPotion}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

For some reason, the textblock that binds to PropertyFromHealthPotion (grandchild of Item) won't display data, yet the other two will. Any ideas why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure you have healthpotion in there? put a `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />` into the DataTemplate to check! Is the property public? if you're expecting it to change, do you RAISE PropertyChanged correctly? By all means, your code SHOULD work....

Comment: I'm such an idiot! I forgot to set the { get; set; } shiznit up at the HealthPotion level...! Thanks for the reply @TDaver :)

Comment: is that it? :) can I get the accept if I post it in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments:

Are you sure you have healthpotion in there? put a  into the DataTemplate to check! Is the property public? if you're expecting it to change, do you RAISE PropertyChanged correctly? By all means, your code SHOULD work....